# Email sent with c# client but not received?

Tags: c#, email, smtp, smtpclient

I'm doing some stuff with an email client. I'm using MailKit and I can see the messages sent but I don't receive them on the email adress specified. As a simple test, I did this console app:

```
public static void Main()
{
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587);
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("****", "@ffice.0123");
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.Send("****", "xxxx", "test", "test");

    Console.WriteLine("sent!");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The message "sent!" is being displayed, there are no exeptions. In outlook the email is been shown as sent:

[image: Example email]

But on the recepient email there is nothing received. Not in inbox, not in spam. Not on gmail, not on yahoo mail. What could be the problem here?

Comment: Use test tool called smtp4dev and try again

Comment: The email can be filtered out by the recipient's email server.

Comment: I used my own personal email accounts. I don't have any filtering and it did not work with any major email service. If I use the outlook smtp server with a "normal" outlook email it works just fine. Tho i haven't heard about smtp4dev, will take a look.